# Taylor series expansion about $x = 3$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series expansion of $f(x)=\sqrt{6x-x^2} $ about $x = 3$.

Looking through my notes, I think this could be solved with the binomial theorem. I am no longer sure binomial theorem is usable. I think I might have to generalize the form of the nth derivative, but I cannot find a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$f(x) = \sqrt{6x-x^2} = \bigl[9 - (x-3)^2\bigr]^{1/2}$$
and now you can apply the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem):
\begin{align*}
\bigl[9 + (-(x-3)^2)\bigr]^{1/2}
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k} 9^{1/2-k} (- (x-3)^2)^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k} 9^{1/2-k} (-1)^k (x-3)^{2k}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I just realized I do not think the binomial theorem generates a Taylor series.

Comment: Do you mean the regular binomial theorem which requires an integer exponent? There is a generalization to noninteger exponents (just edited the answer with a link).

Comment: I believe that it still gives a function about 0

Comment: Please have a look at my edit, is it clear now?

Comment: The binomial theorem *is* a Taylor series. As Arkeet says, the case for $(x+y)^n$, where $n$ is an integer can be generalised to non-integer exponents, which is often called the binomial *series*. But both the binomial theorem and binomial series are just special cases of Taylor series.